# go http client fails after several requests

Tags: http, ssl, go, httprequest, handshake

I am using golang's net/http package in my application. In my use case I am trying to make http calls several times continuously using my custom http client. I am facing following issues with this.

**Issue 1:** After several calls [ ~100 less than a minute], client fails to make calls.I mean the request is not hitting the server.

Here is my custom client code,

```
package serviceclient

import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "log"
)

const(
    HTTP_DIAL_TIME_OUT          = 5    //seconds
    HTTP_TLS_HANDSHAKE_TIME_OUT = 5
    HTTP_CLIENT_TIME_OUT        = 10
)

// RequestService requests the api through the service URL
func RequestService(methodType string, serviceURL string, data string, contentType string) string {
    log.Printf("Request string %s", data)
    dataBytes := bytes.NewBufferString(data)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(methodType, serviceURL, dataBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Client request creation issue")
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", contentType)

    client := getHTTPClient()
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    log.Printf("Response Object original : %s", res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could not make the client request")
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    responseBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Response string conversion issue")
    }
    responseString := string(responseBytes[:])
    return responseString
}

func getHTTPClient() *http.Client {
    var netTransport = &http.Transport{
          Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout: HTTP_DIAL_TIME_OUT * time.Second,
          }).Dial,
          TLSHandshakeTimeout: HTTP_TLS_HANDSHAKE_TIME_OUT * time.Second,
        }
    var client = &http.Client{
          Timeout: time.Second * HTTP_CLIENT_TIME_OUT,
          Transport: netTransport,
        }
    return client
}
```

**Issue 2:** Also every time the client tries to make calls even after successful response with an empty request[Not with the original request]. I mean when I call the RequestService() function it makes 5 extra calls even after getting a successful response. But the `request` value is `undefined` for those calls.

Here is my console output[I printed the http request and few info] for one http call,

```
Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip] User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[160]] 0xc820398180 160 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request Wg
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response &{{127 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SMoqP9eCwM https://www.youtube.com/embed/0SMoqP9eCwM 1} {44 www.github.com/docker 1} 2016-04-09 05:38:32 {} 2016-04-09 05:38:32 [0xc82000c4c0 0xc8200d4da0 0xc82000c600] {1005   0 0    0    []} false}

Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[167] Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]] 0xc8203f4800 167 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request undefined
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response <nil>

Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[167] Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]] 0xc8203f4880 167 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request undefined
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response <nil>

Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[167] Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]] 0xc8203f49c0 167 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request undefined
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response <nil>

Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[167] Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]] 0xc8203f4a40 167 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request undefined
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response <nil>

Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[167] Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]] 0xc8203f4b00 167 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request undefined
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response <nil>

Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[167] Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]] 0xc8203f4c00 167 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request undefined
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response <nil>

Got in appserver ops api  &{GET /api/services/appserverops/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[167] Content-Type:[application/json] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]] 0xc8203f4c80 167 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:57455 /api/services/appserverops/ <nil> <nil>}
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: request undefined
appserveropslogic :: Getappserver() :: response <nil>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: An single http client should be used for all your requests. There's no point in creating many identical clients. As long as the timeouts are the same, just use the same client. It will likely fix your problem. A client is not a connection, it has internal connection pools and caching, etc.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - It helped me solving the first issue I guess [did a simple test]. I appreciate the help. But the other issue still exists :( . Something related to default retries I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what "client" means. it's probably more related to the buffer around the data string.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - I mean when I call the RequestService() function it makes 5 extra calls even after getting a successful response. But the `request` value is `undefined` for those calls.

Comment: you'll need to show how you're doing those 5 extra calls

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - I updated the question with the console output.

Comment: Print the error returned from client.Do.  It will likely explain the first issue. The app is leaking file descriptors because it creates a discards a transport on every request. Use a single transport.